# Store email password in a shared server database

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, password-encryption

I'm building an application using php for server side code, at the moment the customer has a shared server with linux and a mysql database (yes I know it is an horrible solution, but they don't want to spend more money).

The problem is: they asked me to store their email addresses with relative passwords in the application, so they can contact their customers from different addresses without inserting password everytime, but my problem is: how?
I mean, if I use one-way encryption it'll be more secure, but I have to ask password everytime to verify, two-way encryption is more comfortable, but not safe.

Comment: Why do they need you to store passwords to be able to contact customers? Do you mean storing the login details for staff email accounts? If so, using something like LastPass would be a better/safer solution.

Comment: Hey @MattChad. You can use crypto packages or libraries to manage your sensitive data. Modern php frameworks like Laravel, implements .env file that store crypto keys. With crypto keys help PHP code can encrypt / decrypt and save it in DB

Comment: The issue here is that you're storing the e-mail credentials of your customers so that they can send mails through your UI using their own addresses to their own customers, right?

Comment: Yes, think about a "thunderbird in miniature". They want to use the UI for email their customers, so typing password everytime is annoying (and I can see it). But hey, we are on a shared system and they don't want to understand :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two-way encryption would be the way to do this.  If the customer doesn't want to have to insert the password, then the system has to be able to.

But this is okay.  Because these are not *user passwords*.  These are system passwords.  They can be as complex and difficult to remember as you want, because they are literally never typed by a user.  They wouldn't be re-used by the same user on other systems (which is one of the most insecure things about user passwords and why it's dangerous to be able to read them).

The technical concern here is minor, just use a good encryption on the data at rest (the database where the passwords are stored).  The actual concern here is one of educating your customer and advising them of how this works.  The passwords are retrievable, so they should be as random and unusable as possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) yes I know that these are not use password, my fear is that someone can hack the database and then retrieve passowords :P I was thining about use AES as anc. method, you think this is good?